# Problems with LSTM neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am designing a neural network using LSTM with keras library for what I think is a *sequence classification problem*. But I am having problems when fitting the model. This is the problematic code:

```
# create LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4,activation='relu', input_shape=(len(x),1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x,y,epochs = 100, batch_size = 1,verbose=2)
```

When I execute it, I get the following error:

```
> File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 532, in
> _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.PyDBFrame._handle_exception   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\linecache.py",
> line 30, in getline
>     lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\linecache.py",
> line 46, in getlines
>     return updatecache(filename, module_globals)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\linecache.py",
> line 137, in updatecache
>     lines = fp.readlines()   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\codecs.py",
> line 322, in decode
>     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position
> 1465: invalid start byte
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 197, in _run_module_as_main
>     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 87, in _run_code
>     exec(code, run_globals)   File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\__main__.py",
> line 45, in <module>
>     cli.main()   File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py",
> line 444, in main
>     run()   File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py",
> line 285, in run_file
>     runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 288, in run_path
>     return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 97, in _run_module_code
>     _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 87, in _run_code
>     exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\34670\Desktop\UBU\Doctorado\Python\Redes
> Neuronales\Balanceador01\Balanceador01.py", line 54, in <module>  
> File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 1366, in
> _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.SafeCallWrapper.__call__   File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 322, in
> _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.PyDBFrame.trace_exception   File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 452, in
> _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.PyDBFrame.handle_user_exception   File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 535, in
> _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.PyDBFrame._handle_exception   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\linecache.py",
> line 30, in getline
>     lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\linecache.py",
> line 46, in getlines
>     return updatecache(filename, module_globals)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\linecache.py",
> line 137, in updatecache
>     lines = fp.readlines()   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\codecs.py",
> line 322, in decode
>     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position
> 1465: invalid start byte
```

Any idea of what could be problem? I am sure that for example the input_shape of the LSTM layer is ok (I have used `reshape` to convert it to 3D), but I don't understand the error message so I cannot go on.

The input data comes from [this csv file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16xhauH8_l2KrSjWGblZwweBupRx6-hro?usp=sharing) . The first column (number zero) is the time frame, which is not needed as this is a sequence along time. This is how I process the data, very straight forward:

```
# load both voltages and balanceadorOn values
x = pd.read_csv('5 abril 2022.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python')
x = x.values
y = pd.read_csv('5 abril 2022.csv', usecols=[2], engine='python')
y = y.values

# normalize the voltages
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
x = scaler.fit_transform(x)

# Reshape input data to 3D for the LSTM
x = x.reshape(1,len(x),1)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you. **DO NOT** post images data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: From the error message it is pretty clear "utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 1465: invalid start byte" in file File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\codecs.py"  Without more information about your data and what you are trying to do, not much more I can provide

Comment: @itprorh66 I have edit the question in the end with the input data. When I process the data (just reading from CSV file plus re-scaling and reshaping) I don't get any errors. It seems like LSTM does not like it, but I don't understand why. By the way, the x data is the voltage evolution along time, and the y data means that the period of the input signal has decreased (so I can apply an actuator, boolean one).

Comment: You haven't provided input data which can be used for testing.  Telling us that data is pulled from some csv file without giving us a sample of the data is useless information.  Please give us a sample of the x & y data you are processing.  BTW: Don't dump the entire contents but ensure the data provided exhibits the same error

Comment: @itprorh66 "x" is the voltage value along time, and "y" is a boolean value that indicates if the period of the x signal has decreased with respect to the first period (in order to apply an actuator to correct this period change). So this LSTM would predict if the period of the x signal has decreased by putting this boolean from 0 to 1. I have also added a graph to the question description.

Comment: This might be helpful. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9906

Comment: Indeed, it is a Unicode Decode Error.  According to your code, it seems that you have not added input layer to the model. https://keras.io/api/models/sequential/. Like adding tf.keras.Input() to the model before fitting the model to learn. Additionally, this might be helpful. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9906

Comment: Interesting! I will try it and come back here to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the code related with the import of tensorflow, I found this whil looking deeply for this type of error along stack overflow posts. Now I am using the following importing and it works correctly (the difference is that it has *python* between tensorflow and keras):

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM
```